# Why is my CodeHS setTimeout function running inconsistently?

Tags: javascript, audio, settimeout

I am trying to play this looping audio file at a certain time within my code on the CodeHS coding platform in javascript:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        println("Tails");
        var TAILS = new Audio("link");
        TAILS.play();
        TAILS.loop = true;
        println("Tails 2");
    }, delay);
```

`link` and `delay` are placeholders.

I have been running tests and found that this code works correctly 100% of the time with 4900 ms of delay and lower, but becomes inconsistent greater than that, with 10000 ms never running and 5000 ms working around 1 in 4 times.  However, “tails” and “tails 2” both print when the delay is finished every time, no matter the delay. Why is this?

This was originally called as part of a local function `mainWait()` that did some of the calculations for me, but removing this code from that function didn’t fix the issue. I also tried extracting the code inside the first parameter of `setTimeout()` from a function `tailsStart()`, but that also didn’t work.

Comment: `“tails” and “tails 2” both print` so, what doesn't work?

Comment: The link to the audio is static so I would try creating `TAILS` audio object outside the timeout. You can set the `loop` outside the timeout as well. I would also make sure this is the only event that happens on your page and ensure there is a user interaction as well.

Comment: The audio doesn’t play sometimes, despite the text printing

Comment: That is a good idea. I’ll try it, although for some reason the code now works, but only on my computer.

Comment: What does the console print? If anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.